# JPA Unknown Column in Field List

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a relation between `Accommodation` and `Booking` classes, and also I set a foreign key in booking table.

```
ALTER TABLE `project`.`booking` 
ADD INDEX `fk_accId_fk_idx` (`accommodation` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `project`.`booking` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_accId_fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`accommodation`)
  REFERENCES `project`.`accommodation` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Accommodation class:

```
@Entity
  ....
public class Accommodation implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private BigInteger id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accommodation", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List < Booking > bookings;
  ......getters setters
}
```

Booking class:

```
@Entity
public class Booking implements Serializable {
  ......
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "bookings", nullable = true)
  @JsonBackReference
  private Accommodation accommodation;
  ....getters setters
}
```

When I execute a query for listing accommodations, I get unknown column in field list error.

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'bookings7_.bookings' in 'field list'

Even I set the relation and define the foreign key in table, what is the reason that I get this error?

Comment: Everything looks well-designed. Are you sure you have getters and setters of `accommodation` and `bookings` objects?

Comment: @alican.balik you were right... Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to define your join-table mapping manually in JPA. Drop your schema and let JPA create your tables:

Accommodation class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accommodation", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JsonManagedReference
private List < Booking > bookings;
```

Booking class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "accommodation_booking_join_table", 
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="booking_id")},
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "accommodation_id"))
@JsonBackReference
private Accommodation accommodation;
```

Comment: I have solved it, but I have a question according to your answer. What do you mean by Drop your schema and let JPA create? What is the process before JPA creates automatically? Will I not get error if the table doesn't exist in db?  Do I need to set `@Column()` annotation to each variable in my class, otherwise how can JPA know column names?

Comment: Hibernate can auto generate your database tables based on your entities and mappings. Look for this hbm2ddl property of Hibernate which auto generates database tables for you if you set it to create. Look for other properties of hbm2ddl.

Comment: @Malena T first drop your schema with the sql comand "DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;". Then look into your persistence.xml under properties. There add '<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>'

Comment: @Malena T you don't need to add `@Column` to every field, since u already declared you class with `@Entity`, hibernate will interpret every java-field as a table-column in your db. The annotation `@Transient` however will ignore a field as a db-column.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's now clear for me. Also I have a query problem-ish if you may want to check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295109/mysql-query-search-by-dates/43295246?noredirect=1#comment73658424_43295246

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your column names to lower case in your db and entity class.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation like that, and I solved it by changing the field's position on the query. Looks like it's a MySQL bug, like (or the same as) the one mentioned on this post:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1689

The description of this MySQL bug mentioned a similar workaround solution: "I found that by swapping that field's position in the table with another field that it worked OK."