# Mysql Query Search By Dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create a query which shows available hotels between checkin and checkout dates. Also when I make a reservation for specific rooms, I set their booking column as 1. That means, when the checkout date comes in real life, a trigger function will set that booked column as 0.

If all rooms of a hotel are booked(booked=1) and checkin-checkout dates of those rooms are specific date(checkin-checkout inputs), then don't put that hotel in the list. My query doesn't show the result that I want.

Query: Inputs: Country(state), checkin and checkout.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM accommodation a INNER JOIN cb_states s ON a.state = s.id
INNER JOIN accommodation_rooms ar ON a.id = ar.accommodation
WHERE state = 1 AND a.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT 1 FROM booking b
    WHERE
    (
        (b.arrival_date BETWEEN '2017-11-16' AND '2018-03-16') 
        OR
        (b.departure_date BETWEEN '2017-11-16' AND '2018-03-16')
    )
)
```

When I run the query, it always shows all hotels no matter dates. If I write `... WHERE ar.booked = 0 AND state = 1 AND a.id NOT IN...`, then it doesn't show accommodation id 13, but it doesn't show either when I change dates.

accommodation table:
[image: table 1]

accommodation_rooms table:
[image: table 2]

booking table:
[image: table 3]

booked_rooms table:(has foreign key with booking table)
[image: table 4]

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues with your query:

1. The `NOT IN` list has `SELECT 1`.  That doesn't give a great variety to the `NOT IN` list.
2. Your logic for overlaps is wrong.
3. I think you need to connect accommodation rooms to booked accommodation rooms.

So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM accommodation a INNER JOIN
     cb_states s
     ON a.state = s.id INNER JOIN
     accommodation_rooms ar
     ON a.id = ar.accommodation
WHERE s.state = 1 AND
      a.id NOT IN (SELECT br.accommodation_room
                   FROM booking b JOIN
                        booked_room br
                        ON b.?? = br.??
                   WHERE b.arrival_date <= '2018-03-16' AND
                         b.departure_date >= '2017-11-16' 
                  );
```

Comment: What could be the best logic for my situation?

Comment: @MalenaT . . . This has the logic fix.  The `<=` instead of `between` finds *any* overlap.

Comment: I see. Thank you, `b.?? = br.??` here, I wrote `b.id = br.booking` and it still shows a wrong result. Plus, I connected accommodation rooms to booked rooms in subquery `..... JOIN booked_rooms br ON b.id = br.booking JOIN accommodation_rooms aar ON br.room = aar.id`, it shows a wrong result again.